# Vba concatenation

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to concatenate this but it is not working.
I have initialized my array in this way (`Dim Myarray(1 To 2) As String`.)

I dont know weather Myarray has been initialized or not after passing it as string .
i tried debugging the code with (`debug.print`) but i was able to print only one by one values .

But when i print (`myarray`) code mismatch error is coming.

```
Debug.Print Myarray
```

I need both the values in one variable myarray . so that i can pass both the values of the array variable in a single URl and get the expected result

```
    Myarray(1) = 141599734375#
    Myarray(2) = 161631397677#
    'Debug.Print Myarray(1)
     With Sheet1.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://www.ebay.in/itm/" + "Myarray)", _
        Destination:=Sheet1.Range("$A$9"))
```

I have initialized my array in this way (`Dim Myarray(1 To 2) As String`.)
I dont know weather Myarray has been initialized or not after passing it as string .
Please look into the above code and help me resolving this issue.
I am new to VBA,Please  help me solving this issue.

Comment: To concatenate string in VBA use: `&`. If you use array: `somestring = MyArray(0) & " - " &  MyArray(1)`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this.

```
Dim Myarray(0 To 1) As String

Myarray(0) = "141599734375"
Myarray(1) = "161631397677"

Dim myNewArray As String

myNewArray = Join(myArray, ", ")

Debug.WriteLine (myNewArray)
```

For your reference: http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=270:excel-vba-string-functions-split-join-concatenate&catid=79&Itemid=475

Comment: My main intention is to get the page content from ebay(Need only the price) and store it in different cell.

I tried using Single UrL and its working fine,So the reason behind using array is that i can pass multiple URL(I want data to store in my excel )  and i also want to dump data at last .
Please help me solving this.

Comment: My main intention is to get the page content from ebay(Need only the price) and store it in different cell.

I tried using Single UrL and its working fine,So the reason behind using array is that i can pass multiple URL(I want data to store in my excel )  and i also want to dump data at last .
Please help me solving this.

For Eg-
http://www.ebay.in/itm/141599734375
http://www.ebay.in/itm/161631397677

I need to fetch data from from this two URL's

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use both numbers in the array (one after another) this can solve:

```
 With Sheet1.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://www.ebay.in/itm/" & Myarray(0) & Myarray(1)), _
    Destination:=Sheet1.Range("$A$9"))
```

If you need a separetor between the two values you can add it this way:

```
 With Sheet1.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://www.ebay.in/itm/" & Myarray(0) & "separator" & Myarray(1)), _
    Destination:=Sheet1.Range("$A$9"))
```